# preg_match(): Compilation failed

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I try to match this expression:

```
$reg = '/' . str_replace('%','[A-Za-z0-9_-]*', str_replace('.', '\.', $exception)) . '/i';
```

But get have this error :

> 21-Jul-2015 22:15:30 UTC] PHP Warning: preg_match(): Compilation
>   failed: missing ) at offset 12

Comment: Maybe `, ` should have been `.`

Comment: don't see a preg_match() calling

Comment: First str_replace is not closed. After that You have , instead of dot ".". After all you have closed last str_replace twice

Comment: what is your preg_match ? it should be like `preg_match($reg, $string);`

Comment: I think you need to handle more special regex characters, here, [take a look](http://ideone.com/swTfBg). If you have `(`, `)`, `[`, `+` symbols, no wonder you have issues.

Comment: if (preg_match($reg, $key))
                    return false;

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add:

```
$exception = preg_replace('/[()\[\]+$^*?\\\\{]/', '\\\$0', $exception);
```

This will handle the rest of regex metacharacters.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/swTfBg)